# Указатель класса самого на себя

Tags: c++

Не до конца могу уловить плюс от конструкций типа:

```
class Option
{
    public:
        typedef Namespace::SharedPtr<Option> Ptr;
        ....

}
```

`typedef std::vector<Option::Ptr> options;`

В чем плюс такой конструкции? Почему не можно обойтись без `Ptr` и сделать просто `typedef std::vector<Option> option`?

Comment: как обойтись, зависит от намерений  хранить конкретные обьекты или хранить указатели

Comment: @Abyx, но можно тогда просто сделать `std::vector<SharedPtr<Option>> options`?

Comment: @raviga, тогда  options будет обьектом, а в примере это тип, позволяющий написать  options option;

Comment: @raviga Можно. Но каждый раз писать такую портянку не очень удобно. 
 А если вы захотите вдруг перейти к другому типу указателя, вам достаточно будет только изменить typedef (в общем случае), а не искать по всему проекту все места, где вы написали Namespace::SharedPtr<Option>

Comment: @ArHovsepyan а, я понял, что вы имеете ввиду, это я понимаю. вопрос скорее, зачем нужен этот `Ptr`? Можно к примеру сделать `SharedPtr<Option> Ptr = make_shared()`, смысл именно от этого поля `Ptr`? Если сделать экземпляр `Options` тогда у нас будет `Option* option = new Option`, в котором еще будет и `Ptr`. Вот вообще не вижу какой от этого плюс

Comment: @raviga Кажется вы не совсем понимаете смысл typedef. Он лишь создает псевдоним типа, никаких полей классу не добавляется

Comment: @Jester, точно.. ох я очень сильно тупанул. все. теперь понял. спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если добавить немного условного кода, то будет понятнее смысль определений новых имен.

```
namespace Namespace {
    template < class T>
    struct SharedPtr {/*...*/};
}
class Option
{
public:
    typedef  Namespace::SharedPtr<Option> Ptr;
    Ptr mf1();
    void mf2(Ptr);
    //...
private:
    Ptr next;
};
typedef std::vector<Option::Ptr> options;

options& erace(options& v, Option::Ptr)
{ /*...*/ }
//...
```